# how to add eventlistener to elements that have been generated randomly using dom?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I am trying to change the direction of a moving div which is animated in css using keyframes and i want to be able to click on it and change its direction. here is what my code looks like.

HTML

```
     <div id ="div1"></div>
```

CSS

```
   #div1 {
   height:50px;
   width:50px;
   background:red;
   position:relative;
   animation: oldanimation 5s infinite alternate;
      }

   @keyframes newanimation { 
   0% {
   top:0px;
   left:0px;
   }

   100% {    
   top:300px;
   right:300px; 
    } 
   }

  @keyframes oldanimation{
  0% {
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
      }
 100% {
 top:100px;
 left:400px;
 transform:rotate(-45deg);
    }
 }
```

Javascript

```
 div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
 div1.addEventListener('click', newfunc);

 function newfunc () {
 this.style.animationName = 'newanimation';
  }
```

The square div currently moves from left to right and goes slightly downwards and is triggered by keyframes 'oldanimation' by default. So I decided to create a new keyframes animation labeled 'newanimation' and is trigerred when the square is clicked on. I want the square to make a smooth transition from the old path to the new path. currently it just disappears and follows the new path. is there a way to make the transition smooth? sorry for the long question. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Define the `css` `animation` property for a `.className` selector, instead of directly at `#div1` selector, to avoid specificity as to `#div1` selector being primary source of style declaration for the element.

Set the `class` at `html`. Include `transition` set to `all` and appropriate `duration` for the described effect, used `2.5s` at stacksnippets.

At `click` of element get current `left` and `top` `css` property values using `window.getComputedStyle()`; append a transition `@keyframes` declaration to `style` element with `left` and `top` set from current position of element.

At `animationend` event of transitioning animation, set `"newanimation"` to `animation` property of element `.style` property.

```js
 div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
 div1.addEventListener("click", newfunc);
 
 function toggleAnimation() {

   this.className = "";
   this.style.animation = "newanimation 5s infinite alternate";
   this.removeEventListener("animationend", toggleAnimation);

  }

 function newfunc() {

   this.removeEventListener("click", newfunc);
   var left = window.getComputedStyle(this).left;
   var top = window.getComputedStyle(this).top;
   var css = `@keyframes to {
                from {
                  left: ${left};
                  top: ${top};
                }
                to {
                  left: 0px;
                  top: 0px;
                }
             }`;
             
  document.querySelector("style").textContent += `\n\n${css}`;
  this.style.animation = "to 2.5s 1 forwards";
  this.addEventListener("animationend", toggleAnimation);
  
 }
```

```css
#div1 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.originalAnimation {
  animation: oldanimation 5s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes oldanimation {
  0% {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  100% {
    top: 100px;
    left: 400px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
}

@keyframes newanimation {
  0% {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 300px;
    right: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="originalAnimation"></div>
```

See also [Pausing CSS animation with javascript and also jumping to a specific place in the animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080548/pausing-css-animation-with-javascript-and-also-jumping-to-a-specific-place-in-th/)